# Outlook JS web add-in: can't get to, cc or bcc field from mail item in classic desktop Outlook composer if activated by mailto link

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I'm writing an Outlook JS web add-in. It has an event-based activation on the `onNewMessageCompose` event.

In my `onNewMessageComposeHandler` function, I am trying to retrieve the to, cc and bcc fields of the mail item:

```js
function onNewMessageComposeHandler(event) {
  Office.context.mailbox.item.to.getAsync(result => console.log(JSON.stringify(result)));
}
```

When the composer is activated by a `mailto` link such as `mailto:email@example.com`, the code logs the `to` field normally in the web based "new" Outlook for Windows:

```js
{
    "value": [{
        "emailAddress": "email@example.com",
        "displayName": "email@example.com",
        "recipientType": "other"
    }],
    "status": "succeeded"
}
```

but if I change the default app to handle `mailto` to the classic desktop Outlook app, the code always logs an empty array:

```js
{
    "value": [],
    "status": "succeeded"
}
```

The same thing happens to `cc` and `bcc` fields when the composer is triggered by `mailto:email1@example.com?cc=email2@example.com&bcc=email3@example.com`.

I've even tried putting in a 2 second wait just to test things out but the outcome is exactly the same:

```js
function onNewMessageComposeHandler(event) {
  setTimer(
    () => Office.context.mailbox.item.to.getAsync(result => console.log(JSON.stringify(result))),
    2000);
}
```

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not great but currently "as designed". The problem is that classic outlook does not resolve these recipients quickly enough for this API to work during the on new message compose event. It's a race condition between these two operations on this client. I expect this would work if you try a longer delay - does it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Oleg, much appreciated. I wish this information was mentioned on the event based activation documentation page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch, or the onNewMessageCompose event walkthrough page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/on-new-compose-events-walkthrough, to save us the week of investigating down this rabbit hole.

Comment: I suppose a better way to handle this scenario would be to also add a handler for the OnMessageRecipientsChanged event - you'd get this event when Outlook completes the recipient resolution for those recipients. That way you wouldn't have do any unnatural delays in processing in your code. I'll bring doc improvement suggestion up with my team, thanks!